# ERROR 1064 (42000): SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, cmd, mysql-error-1064

MYSQL command

I'm using command prompt

```
create table user
  <id int<11> unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
   username jack<25> not null, 
   passwd jack<25> not null, 
   email jack<40> not null>;
```

the error

> ERROR 1064 <42000>: you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near'table user' at line 1

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

**First :** use `()` instead of `<>`
**Second :** use `varchar` instead of `jack`, jack is incorrect datatype

so query should be :

```
create table user (  /* <-- note the brackets */
       id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
       username varchar(25) not null, /*incorrect data type "jack"*/
       passwd varchar(25) not null, /*use varchar instead of jack */
       email varchar(40) not null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you appear to be using angle brackets rather than parentheses. Second, I'm not sure what `jack` is supposed to be but it's not standard SQL.

I'd be starting with this instead (though you could also use `varchar` instead of `char`):

```
create table user (
    id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
    username char(25) not null, 
    passwd char(25) not null, 
    email char(40) not null
);
```

Comment: Thank you  I got new information, I thought I should write the name of the user after  username.....

Comment: @DuaaIsaa: no, what you have there is DDL, data _definition_ language. All it does is create structures for the data. The data itself is done with DML or data _manipulation_ language, such as `insert` or `update`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use parentheses instead of angle brackets
2. Use Valid DataType

Try this

```
   create table user(id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
   username varchar(25) not null, 
   passwd varchar(25) not null, 
   email varchar(40) not null);
```